# Expected catch() or return [promise/catch-or-return] and Each then() should return a value or throw [promise/always-return]

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I am getting two errors in line 11 and 12. that

**Expected catch() or return [promise/catch-or-return]  and Each then() should return a value or throw [promise/always-return]**

i am trying to deploy a ExpressJS API to Firebase Hosting

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    var qu = req.param('q');
    const DuckDuckScrape = require("duck-duck-scrape");
const ddg = new DuckDuckScrape();
    var search = ddg.search(qu, -1, "en-us");
    search.then((data) => {
        res.send(data)
      }) ;  


  });

  exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Please help me out by solving the issue.

Comment: Try adding a `.catch((error) => { // Handle error })` after `then`

Comment: can you give a sample code? I tried this solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is making those two errors?  Is it a lint program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an error from some sort of lint program, not from the actual Javascript interpreter.  If that's the case, then you can probably make the linter happy with this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const DuckDuckScrape = require("duck-duck-scrape");


app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    const qu = req.param('q');
    const ddg = new DuckDuckScrape();
    ddg.search(qu, -1, "en-us").then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
  });

  exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This covers a couple possible lint issues.  First, there's a `.catch()` so there's no missing error handling.  Second, there's no promise left hanging around that the linter thinks you might use later and thus it complains about no return value from the  `.then()`.

If you still get the second warning, I'd probably find the config and turn off that warning because it's overzealous here as no return value is need from the `.then()`, but you could also just add a `return null;` or change to `return res.send(data)` if you really just wanted the warning to go away.  I personally don't add unnecessary code just to make irrelevant lint warnings go way.  I'd rather disable the faulty warning.

Comment: I just changed **return res.send(data);**  and the errors went away. But while deploying, it gives a error message,

Comment: @SubhajitMondal - Since you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.